# Prove $R(TS) = R(T)$ if and only if $R(S) + N(T) = V$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is to prove $R(TS) = R(T)$ if and only if $R(S) + N(T) = V$, where $T \in L(V, W)$ and $S \in L(U, V)$.
I have absolutely no idea why this would be true, and hence could not make any progress. Any help would be great.

Comment: The main difficulty with the equality would be if there are elements of $R(T)$ that can be reached using $T$ but only from points that are *not* in $R(S)$, because then you woudln't be able to obtain them as elements in $R(TS)$. That suggests that you want to make sure that that the range of $S$ is "large enough". Large enough for what? Large enough to get everything you can get from $T$. How much can you get from $T$? Well, that depends on how big $N(T)$ is (the larger $N(T)$, the less you can get from $T$). That may explain why you want to take a look at $R(S)+N(T)$.

Comment: Hint: Note that $R(TS)\subseteq R(T)$ always holds, so this is really about proving that $R(T)\subseteq R(TS)$ if and only if $R(S)+N(T)=V$ holds. Now, **follow your nose**. Pick $w\in R(T)$. Then there exists $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=w$. Now, since $v\in V=R(S)+N(T)$, then...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the help!!! I still lack full understanding of the intuition but I think you are explaining that as N(T) grows, R(S) decreases. But I will need to look into it more to understand the equality under the condition.

I hope you can take a look at my proof.

Continuing off from your hint:
So $\exists u \in U$ and $v^' \in N(T)$ s.t $v = S(u) + v^'$
$\implies T(v) = T(S(u)) + T(v^') = T(S(u)) \implies v \in R(S)$

Comment: And this is my progress so far for the other direction:
We know V is closed under addition so $R(S) + N(T) \subseteq V$
So let $v \in V$. Then, $T(v) \in R(T) = R(TS)$.
So $\exists u \in U$ s.t. $T(S(u)) = T(v)$. And of course I was like $v = S(u)$ but $S$ could be surjective. So I do not know how to proceed from here. Any help would be very great.

Comment: You aren’t trying to show that $T(v)\in R(S)$; you are trying to show that $w\in R(TS)$. You lost sight of where you were going. As for the converse, while you do not know that $v=S(u)$, you *do* know what happens to $v-S(u)$ when hyou apply $T$ to it. Which means that $v-S(u)$ lies in...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin
You are right. We know:
$w = T(v) = T(S(u))  \implies w \in R(TS)$ and I think that's how it should finish..?

And again thank you haha. Hopefully this one is correct.
Then, $T(v - S(u)) = 0 \implies v - S(u) \in N(T)$
Since $v = v - S(u) + S(u)$ and $S(u) \in R(S), v \in R(S) + N(T)$

Comment: Haha it's often weird how even when I don't have the full intuition behind it, the proof makes sense.